# Make an image look like it is placed over 2 <div> boxes with CSS

Tags: css, image, position

[image]

Hello I need to position an image as in the example. Theoretically it looks like it is positioned over 2 seperate  boxes with different background colors, that is the goal, but practically it is not possible, at least for me. How to solve the problem?

Comment: maybe you want z-index?

Comment: thank you looks like that is exactly what I was looking for, but did not know until now.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution will be using a combination of an  of `z-index` and `position:absolute`.

*A small suggestion if you may encounter the problem: you must use `z-index` with specifying the position (`position: static` will not work)

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png'>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hello, the first DIV that then arrives at the sticky navbar pushes the navbar off the screen, is there a solution for this as well?

Comment: @cabanni, the possible reason (I don't have your code) is you doesn't specify the position for `navoff`, so the `navof`f will be `position:static`, a possible solution is to use  `position:absolute` for `navoff`, so the `div` will not effect it

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd do this with `flex` and vertical alignment, but since you want specifically the image to be between boxes i'd say `absolute` is the way to go here

```css
.card {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 80px; /* image width + 20px */
}

.header, .image-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.image-container {
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container .image {
  display; inlnie-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, nice answer without `z-index`, do you mind a little bit explaining how you make the image to place over another element?

Comment: @james sure. For a div to appear, it needs at least a height, so `1px` here, this places a "row" between the two elements that are rows too. Then you place your image moving it to the empty space (hence the empty space of margin in the card), using translate to both move it 100% to the left, where the margin is displayed, and half the top so it's centered in its container of 1px. Changing the sizes of either the boxes or the image will not move anything else, the only downside is to margin the card according to the image width